# Tensorflow function tfa.optimizers.extend_with_decoupled_weight_decay() Raises Exception upon Execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-addons

Recently, I’ve been working on machine learning using Tensorflow 2. My code requires the `tfa.optimizers.extend_with_decoupled_weight_decay()` function implemented in the Tensorflow-addons package (TFA).
However, during execution, the code raises a rare exception to which I cannot find a resolution or explanation anywhere on the internet.
Any help clarifying the problem would be much appreciated!

**Here is the specifications of the platforms and versions I am using:**

OS: Windows 11
Python: 3.10.9
Tensorflow: 2.13.0
Tensorflow Addons: 0.21.0

**The example code found on [Tensorflow's website](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/extend_with_decoupled_weight_decay)** 
this raises the exception, similarly to the code in my project:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa


# MyAdamW is a new class
MyAdamW = tfa.optimizers.extend_with_decoupled_weight_decay(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam)
# Create a MyAdamW object
optimizer = MyAdamW(weight_decay=0.001, learning_rate=0.001)
# update var1, var2 but only decay var1
optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1, var2], decay_variables=[var1])
```

**The error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    optimizer = MyAdamW(weight_decay=0.001, learning_rate=0.001)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py", line 1033, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\optimizers\weight_decay_optimizers.py", line 369, in __init__
    super().__init__(weight_decay, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py", line 1033, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\optimizers\weight_decay_optimizers.py", line 99, in __init__
    self._set_hyper("weight_decay", wd)
AttributeError: 'OptimizerWithDecoupledWeightDecay' object has no attribute '_set_hyper'
```

Suspecting an incompatibility with the addons package.
I tried downgrading it to `0.20.0` and `0.19.0`, but the same exception appeared without any change.